# Salesforce Java Streaming Client filtered subscription

Tags: java, streaming-api, cometd

I am subscribing to a push topic from a Salesforce Streaming java client that uses the cometd and bayeux libraries. I found this page which says that filtered subscriptions are supported in streaming https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_filtered_subscriptions.htm.

To try this I am doing client.getChannel("/topic/Updates?Name='Account'") where client is an object of org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient. My issue is that when I subscribe using this code I do not get any notifications for inserts etc from this PushTopic.

How do I filter the subscription using the java streaming client?